# Android : Lagging for a TranslateAnimation

Tags: android, animation, slowdown, translate-animation

I have to realize a "scan bar" animation, making an animation of translation (a bit like the google goggles app). It's a bar picture (custom view), which cross my surfaceview from left to right.

I did something that is close to my expectations, except that the animation lagging :(

This is a part of my XML :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutCamera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="8" >

    <SurfaceView 
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my custom wiew :

```
class ScannerView extends View 
{
private Bitmap scanBar;
private int sizeBarW;
private int sizeBarH;   

public ScannerView(Context context, int heightParent) 
{
    super(context);     

    //init size
    sizeBarW = 5;
        //I adjust the height of the bar to my surfaceview
    sizeBarH = heightParent;

    //prepare bitmap
    scanBar = prepareBitmap(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.scan_bar), sizeBarW,
            sizeBarH);      
}

private static Bitmap prepareBitmap(Drawable drawable, int width, int height) 
{
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    canvas.drawBitmap(scanBar, 0, 0, null);
}
}
```

And this is my animation function (called on surfaceChanged() from my activity class):

```
private void LaunchAnimation()
{
    // 1 - view
    mScanBar = new ScannerView(this, surfaceView.getHeight());
    addContentView(mScanBar, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    // 2 - Animation
    Animation animTranslation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f,
                                                       Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    animTranslation.setDuration(5000);
    animTranslation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    mScanBar.startAnimation(animTranslation);
}
```

I am beginner in android programming and I'm not sure I do it the best way... :?

Thank you to help me to resolve this lagging/slow-down problem. :)

Comment: does it do it on an actual device? the emulator is notoriously slow

Comment: Yes, in my nexus s ... In fact, the bar moves smoothly, then it freezes, and it off again ...